# NP complete - solvable in non-deterministic polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, np-complete

It is written in a book that --"If a problem A is NP-Complete, there exists a non-deterministic polynomial time algorithm to solve A" . But as far I know 'yes' -answer for NP complete problems can be "verified" in polynomial time. I am really confused. Can a NP-complete problem be "solved" using non-deterministic polynomial time algorithm?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [cs.se].

Comment: If you can check in polynomial time, then you can nondeterministically solve in polynomial time: just start checking all possible solutions, and keep the solution that solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Finding* the solution to an NP-complete problem can be done in polynomial time on a non-deterministic Turing machine. Given a candidate solution of an NP-complete problem, it can be verified whether it is indeed a solution or not, i.e. *checked*, in polynomial time on a deterministic Turing machine.

So the difference is in *finding* a solution and *checking* a solution. The former usually requires some kind of search for NP-complete problems while the latter is just verifying the assignments to your variables.

Comment: Note that this is true generally for NP problems, not just for NP-complete problems.

Answer (score 6):

The two things are basically identical and are based on two different though equivalent definition of NP.

Every problem (language) in NP must be:

1. Verified in polynomial time by a deterministic turing machine. (given a problem and a 'verification', you can answer if the verification is correct for the problem in a polynomial time).

   **Example:** Given a graph, and you want to check if there is a hamiltonian path in it - the verifier can be the path. You can easily check if the path is indeed hamiltonian once you have it.
2. Solved in polynomial time by a non deterministic turing machine. (there exists non deterministic Turing Machine `M` that can solve the problem polynomially)

Since by definition of NP-Complete - a problem is NP Complete if it is NP-Hard AND in NP, every NP-Complete problem is also NP - and both are correct.

---

Note that those two claims are basically based on the two equivalent definitions for NP:

1. A language `L` is in NP if for each `x` in `L` there is a word `z` such that `|z|` is polynomial in `|x|`, and there exists some deterministic turing machine that runs in polynomial time `M` - such that for each `x` and its matching `z`,: `M(x,z) = true if and only if x is in L`
2. A problem is in NP if there is a non deterministic turing machine that can solve the problem in polynomia time. Formally, a language `L` is in NP if there is a non deterministic turing machine such that `M(x) = true if and only if x is in L`

Comment: Note that *both* of those conditions need to be true for a problem to be NP-complete. E.g. problems in P can also be verified in deterministic poly-time, but that doesn't make them NP-complete.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Those two conditions are equivalent and are based on 2 equivalent definition of NP, if one holds - the other holds as well.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the earlier version of the post that didn't have the part below the line.